# Plotting Monte Carlo Paths in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, montecarlo

I am experimenting in R shiny. I'm currently trying to create a graph in shiny that plots the different paths of the monte carlo simulations.

I've tried different plot methods ts.plot(), ggplot(), plot() but these methods either give no output or a box with no graphical representation whatsoever.

```r
ui <- fluidpage(
titlePanel("test"),

sidebarPanel(

numericinput("sim";"give simulations", min=1, value=100),

sliderinput("first", "first value", min =1, max =1000, value  =c(0,1000)),

sliderinput("second", "second value", min =1, max =1000, value = c(0,1000)),

submitButton()
),

mainPanel(

verbatimTextoutput("summa"),

plotOutput("test")
)
)
```

```
server <- function(input,output,session){
output$summa <- renderPrint({summary(runif(input$sim,input$first[1],input$first[2]))})

#graphing monte carlo 
output$test <- renderHighchart({

for(simu in 1:input$sim){

first <- runif(1,input$first[1],input$first[2])
second <- runif(1,input$second[1],input$second[2])
third <- first + second
)

ts.plot(third)

})

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

When I run the above it just gives an empty box with no lines. when I use the plot() function it just show a single dot.

I would very much like to see multiple paths depending on the number of simulations that were selected.

If anybody could help me or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using `lines` to add your paths? You only need to `plot` your first path and then keep adding the new paths with `lines`. Try to make it work without `shiny` first.

Comment: I have tried plot(third)    for(i in 1: input$sim){ lines(rnorm(third) } but to no avail